# Finding missing numbers in a list in Perl

Tags: linux, perl

For instance, given ( 1, 2, 5, 6, 7), i'd like to determine that 3 and 4 are missing?

I've found  following code which achieves my goal.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Data::Dumper;
@list= (1,2,5,6,7);
@missing = map $list[$_-1]+1..$list[$_]-1, 1..@list-1;
print Dumper(\@missing);
```

Output:

```
$VAR1 = [
          3,
          4
        ];
```

Can someone please explain the logic behind above code?

Comment: Not sure where you got that code, but I have one slight quibble with it. `@list-1` is better written as `$#list`. `@list` in scalar context gives you the the number of elements in `@list` and subtracting one from that gives you the last index in the array. But `$#list` is a special variable that gives you the last index in `@list` without requiring the subtraction. It's more efficient and it better expresses your intention.

Comment: Oh. Actually I have another problem with that code. `@list` is a terrible name for an array variable. It promotes the incorrect (but depressingly common) idea that arrays and lists in Perl are the same thing.

Comment: @DaveCross Thanks for the information. I have taken the code from here : http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=388315

Comment: And I see that [a reply there](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=388325) had exactly the same quibbles as I did :-)

Comment: @Dave Cross, Re "*It's more efficient*", It's either a tiny tiny tiny bit more efficient or many many times less efficient depending on your version of Perl and how you use it. For example, `f(\@a, 0, $#a)` is less efficient than `f(\@a, 0, @a-1)` no matter what version of Perl you use. But talking of efficient here is *silly*!

Comment: Everyone needs a little silliness in their life occasionally :-) And perhaps I was talking about programmer efficiency (ok, you got me - I wasn't). But I'd be fascinated to read more about the example you cite. Do you have a link to a detailed explanation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> map **EXPR**,**LIST**
>
> Evaluates the BLOCK or EXPR for each element of LIST
>   (locally setting $_ to each element) and returns the list value
>   composed of the results of each such evaluation.

In your case:

```
map $list[$_-1]+1..$list[$_]-1, 1..@list-1;
```

**LIST: `1..@list-1`:** Is a list which contains elements from 1 to 4 (array length-1)

**EXPR: `$list[$_-1]+1..$list[$_]-1`:**  Uses the index from above (1 to 4) and evaluates expression with range operator.

At each iteration below happens:

```
$list[1-1]+1..$list[1]-1: 1+1..2-1 = ''
$list[2-1]+1..$list[2]-1: 2+1..5-1 = 34
$list[3-1]+1..$list[3]-1: 5+1..6-1 = ''
$list[4-1]+1..$list[4]-1: 6+1..7-1 = ''
```